# Creating a custom RouteBase in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've implemented a custom Route `MyCustomRoute` by inheriting from `RouteBase`

I've orerridden `GetRoutData` and the method is invoked as long as I use an URL like `/XY`.
However the method is not invoked when I call an URL like `/XY.htm` or `/XY.pdf` I guess somewhere I have to instruct my app that also "Files" needs to be processed by the rounting

That's what I have in `RegisterRoutes`

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Add(new MyCustomRoute());
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

What do I need to do so that "Files" can also be processed by my Route?

Answer (score 0):

Well, normally, by default the routing system will ignore the request to a file extension that hasn't been mapped to and then the IIS static file handler will take over.

What happens is that the `/XY` is mapped  and processed with the "Default" route you specified. However, static files are processed by the static files handler instead of the MVC Routing system. You will need to stop IIS from handling static files. There's a bit more involved on that and you can find more details in [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-routing-intercepting-file-requests-like-index-html-and-what-it-teaches-about-how-routing-works)